# 'If' statement causing unit test to fail, but I don’t know why

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-testing, django-tests

I have the following unit test and cannot figure out why it's failing (the test passes if I remove `if(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') != request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('page1'))):`), though I can't figure out how to make the test pass with it still there.

#### File *tests.py*

```
def test_redirects_after_POST(self):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser('username')
        self.client.force_login(user)

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('page1'), data={
            'first_name': 'testuser',
            'dob': UnitTest.set_age(20)}
        )

        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('page2'))
```

I have tried adding this, but it doesn’t help:

```
referer = 'http://testserver{}'.format(reverse('page1'))
# Also tried: referer = 'http://testserver{}'.format(reverse('page2'))
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('page1'), data={
            'first_name': 'testuser',
            'dob': UnitTest.set_age(20)}
            , HTTP_REFERER=referer)
```

#### File *views.py*

```
@login_required
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'registered_user'])
def page1(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Page1Form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.page1)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('page2')

    else:
        form = Page1Form(instance=request.user.page1)

    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request, 'website/page1.html', context)

@login_required
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'registered_user'])
def page2(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Page2Form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.page2)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('page3')
    else:
        # redirect if user didnt access the page from page1
        if(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') != request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('page1'))):
            return redirect('page1')

        else:
            form = Page2Form(instance=request.user.page2)

    context = {
        'form' : form
    }

    return render(request, 'website/page2.html', context)
```

#### Error message

```
AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve redirection page '/website/page2/': response code was 302 (expected 200)
```

Comment: A 302 is a redirect, so that is a successful POST, in that sense the test was *succesful*.

Comment: haha oh. thank you.. i read that 302 was a redirect, but because my test ```self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('page2'))``` fails i thought it must have redirected for another reason. Do you have any idea why that test is failing then please? If it redirects successfully id expect that test to pass. EDIT- this has been answered. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *"the test passes is i remove the check"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry, I changed it to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request succeeded, but your test failed, because you coded the wrong [expectations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects):

> If your request used the follow argument, the expected_url and target_status_code will be the url and status code for the final point of the redirect chain.

Yet, your request didn't set follow to true, since it defaults to false.

Comment: Ahh, thank you.
The following test now passes: ```self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('needs_analysis'), status_code=302, target_status_code=302, fetch_redirect_response=True)```, though shouldnt the target_status_code=200, as the post should redirect (status_code=302), then page2 should load successfully (target_status_code=200)?

Comment: You need to add follow=True to self.client.post(). Then target_status_code should be 200. Unless page_2 is failing because of the referer mismatch. What does `response["HTTP_LOCATION"]` say?

Comment: Ahh I need to add it to the POST. Okay, I added ```, follow=True``` after POST and ```self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('page2'), status_code=302, target_status_code=200, fetch_redirect_response=True)``` is telling me ```Response redirected to '/website/page1/', expected '/website/page2/```

Comment: This should work. HTTP_REFERER should be retained on redirects, via Client._handle_redirects(). You should print `response.redirect_chain` and in the page_2 view the two values you're comparing to see the difference.

Comment: Ahh yes, its because I stupidly removed HTTP_REFERER when I added follow=True. Having both of these after POST now passes. It also makes perfect sense to me. Thank you very much.